# Using this json file in html

Tags: html, json

I have this json file. I want to implement this in a html file. I have minimal idea of json.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var arr = [[11, 123, 1236, "One"], [45, 92, 1067, "Two"], 
  [24, 104, 1176, "Three"], [50, 23, 610, "Four"], 
  [18, 17, 539, "Five"], [7, 89, 864, "Six"], [2, 13, 1026, "Seven"]];

 var plot1b = $.jqplot('chart1b',[arr],{
 title: 'Tooltip and Custom Legend Highlighting',
 seriesDefaults:{
  renderer: $.jqplot.BubbleRenderer,
  rendererOptions: {
    bubbleAlpha: 0.6,
    highlightAlpha: 0.8,
    showLabels: false
  },
  shadow: true,
  shadowAlpha: 0.05
}
});
$.each(arr, function(index, val) {
$('#legend1b').append('<tr><td>'+val[3]+'</td><td>'+val[2]+'</td></tr>');
});
$('#chart1b').bind('jqplotDataHighlight', 
function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data, radius) {    
  var chart_left = $('#chart1b').offset().left,
    chart_top = $('#chart1b').offset().top,
    x = plot1b.axes.xaxis.u2p(data[0]),  // convert x axis unita to pixels
    y = plot1b.axes.yaxis.u2p(data[1]);  // convert y axis units to pixels
  var color = 'rgb(50%,50%,100%)';
  $('#tooltip1b').css({left:chart_left+x+radius+5, top:chart_top+y});
  $('#tooltip1b').html('<span style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;color:' + 
  color + ';">' + data[3] + '</span><br />' + 'x: ' + data[0] + 
  '<br />' + 'y: ' + data[1] + '<br />' + 'r: ' + data[2]);
  $('#tooltip1b').show();
  $('#legend1b tr').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
  $('#legend1b tr').eq(pointIndex+1).css('background-color', color);
});

$('#chart1b').bind('jqplotDataUnhighlight', 
  function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
      $('#tooltip1b').empty();
      $('#tooltip1b').hide();
      $('#legend1b tr').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
  });
});
```

I dont have much idea about json.
How do I implement this json file in html?
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use it with a template engine in your html like mustache or handlebars. It is very easy to learn and quick made....

Here is the link to handlebars. It used it for a project and it is more comfortable than mustache (it is based on it).

http://handlebarsjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is not JSON. It is Jquery script. You can add it to html page by writing it inside the `<script></script>` tag.

Comment: I wrote it inside <script> </script> tag, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a JSON File, it's a jQuery Script called on dome ready. So it will be appended to the html page directly.